# question about future that not happened now

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense

I have this sentence:

> Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX university and I **would have known** many great professors at YYY university, I will be able to make combined research projects.

I haven't studied at `YYY` university yet, but I am talking about what I'll do after I have finished studying at `YYY` university.

Is the expression `would have known` being used correctly?

Comment: Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX and I'm sure I will build many great relationships with professors at YYY, I will be able to conduct combined[joint] research projects that would not otherwise be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider your sentence,

> Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX university and I **?[would have known]** many great professors at YYY university, I will be able to **?[make]** combined research projects.

The use of *would have known* suggests the 'unreal' past. This is a result of the use of the modal verb *would* with a perfect infinitive *(to) have known*. The same result applies to the modal verbs *could*, *might*, *ought*, *should*, *would*, and *needn't*.

The other problem is the verb *make*. We don't normally say *make a project*, we can say *do a project*, or more formally *conduct a project*, as others suggested. In my opinion, those alternatives fit your context well; and I would like to offer another alternative: *make projects possible*.

Let's make our first rough edit,

> Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX university and I **will have known** many great professors **after a while** at YYY university, I will be able to make combined[joint] research projects **possible**.

I added *possible* for the verb *make*, and noted an alternative of *combined*, *joint*, as Jim suggested. (I prefer *joint*, but *combined* is also widely used.) The problematic part *would have known* was replaced by *will have known*. The modal verb *will* with a perfect infinitive can refer to situations that are not unreal, but uncertain. (Modal verbs for uncertain situations when being used with perfect infinitives are *could*, *should*, *ought to*, *may*, *will*, and *must*.) However, *will have known* is in the future perfect form, and thus, we should add a reference time. You can replace *after a while* with other time expression of your choice.

Having said that, why don't we keep it simple? Let's try to keep the changes at the minimum.

> Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX university and I **will come to know** many great professors at YYY university, I **would** be able to make *joint* research projects ***possible***.

Instead of using perfect tenses, let's consider something simple and straightforward. I used *come to know* (meaning "become familiar with"), added the word *possible*, and that's it! Changing *will be able* to *would be able* is not necessary, but I suggested it to soften the assertion a little.

As a bonus, here is how I would rephrase your sentence from another perspective.

> I have good relationships with professors at XXX university, and I **wish to develop such good relationships with** many great professors at YYY university **because I want to** be able to make *joint* research projects ***possible***.

The "will come to know" is more direct and result-oriented. The "wish to develop" is more humble and passion-oriented. I personally feel comfortable to use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

`would have known` is **past tense** and implies that you have missed an opportunity to know the great professors at YYY university.

You can reframe your sentence to include **intent**:

> *I will be able* to use the  good relationships *I will build* with the many great professors at YYY university, along with those *I have already built* with professors at XXX university, to *conduct* combined research projects.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping it simple, I'd prefer this -

> *Since I have good relationships with professors at XXX university and **the same I will develop/have** with many great professors at YYY university, I will be able to do combined research projects.*

As Nomic stated, *would have known* in this context would be a *missed opportunity.*

Comment: "the same I will develop with" is not good English.